# Triangle next to username not displayed on Android

Tags: bug, status-completed

In chrome, on the newest version of Android, the little arrow link to the left of my username at the top of the page is not visible.

The link is still there but I have to click blindly and hope that I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird, looks like that character just flat out doesn't exist in latest Android.  Not really sure how that happens.

Anyway, we've got a slightly different arrow we use in other places that *does* work so starting with the next build the arrow in the top bar will be replaced with that.

Comment: It's fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it's there on my nexus 7, running jelly bean 4.2.2. Perhaps a caching issue? Does it occur on all stack exchange sites?